# Java: new AbstractClass(){} What is this declaration called?

Tags: java, abstract-class

In my application there is an abstract class which is used multiple time as follows:

```
public class Myclass{
    int amount;
    String name;
    public void printResultsFromDB(){
        new MyabstractClass(name){
            @Override
            String getDataFromDB(){
                //some implementation
            }
        };
    }
}

public abstract MyabstractClass{
    String name;
    public MyabstractClass(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    abstract String getDataFromDB();
    void execute(){
        //Some implementation
    }
}
```

I want to know what line number 5 in code called?
I know we cannot instantiate an abstract class. Is this declaration called an anonymous class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a anonymous class which will allow you to implement an interface.

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

> The anonymous class expression consists of the following:
>
> - The new operator
> - The name of an interface to implement or a class to extend. In this    example, the anonymous class is implementing the interface
>     HelloWorld.
> - Parentheses that contain the arguments to a constructor, just like a    normal class instance creation expression. Note: When you
>     implement    an interface, there is no constructor, so you use an
>     empty pair of    parentheses, as in this example.
> - A body, which is a class declaration body. More specifically, in the    body, method declarations are allowed but statements are not.

Answer (score 2):

This is called an anonymous type in Java. It allows you to implement an interface or extend an abstract class without needing a named class for it.

This is especially useful if the interface or abstract class is implemented very often and creating a new class for each implementation would end up in a confusing mess of classes. A good example for this is Java's `Runnable` interface that simply allows to pass a `void` method to a method which takes no arguments.

You can find more on this here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

You're not instantiating an abstract class. It's an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that extends MyabstractClass. It still has to provide an implementation of any abstract methods.

It's meant for cases where you want to provide some custom implementation for one case but you don't expect to reuse it anywhere else.